# Creating 'thankyou' popup for PHP form using colorbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, colorbox

I am already using colorbox on my site so would like to use the inlineHTML colorbox to present a user with a thankyou feedback once they have submitted the form.

I've set up the inline content contact_thanks which contains the thankyou text, as a hidden div.

I've then set the PHP script to reroute to my domain + #contact_thanks

The only problem is, I'm missing some part that calls the jQuery to change the colorbox div from hidden, and I'm not sure what I need to put in my code to make this work.

Live site can be found [here](http://www.haselden.co.uk/james/index.php), feel free to send test messages (it only goes to me at the mo!)

**The PHP**

```
<?php
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

  mail( "myemail@gmail.com", "Message",
    $message, "From: $email" );
  header( "Location: http://www.mysite.co.uk/james/index.php#contact_thanks" );
?>
```

**The HTML**

```
<div style='display:none'>
      <div id='contact_thanks' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
      <span class="colorBox">Thank you for your message!</span>
      <p>Thanks!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the popup to display on page load, you need to call your popup from `$(function() { ... });` in jQuery. I would send a querystring variable and test that.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more with some example code? I'm not entirely sure how to call this function within the PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this  to your .js file (assuming you have jQuery loaded):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if( window.location.hash == '#contact_thanks' ) {
      $('#contact_thanks').show();
    } 
});
```

But you also need to edit your html:

```
<div id='contact_thanks' style='padding:10px; background:#fff; display:none'>
    <span class="colorBox">Thank you for your message!</span>
    <p>Thanks!</p>
</div>
```

Actually, it's much better to move all styles to your css and apply to #contact_thanks. And there is better option, but it will be a bit harder to implement - send your form data via .ajax() and then show your message after success.

Comment: Hi, I tried this with no luck. I also tried just putting that function in the head of the file to check it wasn't a problem with the external file, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @FrancescaHaselden, it worked for me. I've changed window.load to document.ready, check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ACJGH/2/

Here is a working demo -

no hash: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ACJGH/3/show/
with hash: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ACJGH/3/show/#contact_thanks

Also double-check you have jQuery loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if( window.location.hash == '#contact_thanks' ) {
      $('#contact_thanks').show();
    } 
});
```

With this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( window.location.hash == '#contact_thanks' ) {
      $.colorbox({inline:true, href:'#contact_thanks', width:700});
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not hiding the `#contact_thanks` `div`, but some unnamed `div` instead:

```
<div style="display: none">
  <div id="contact_thanks" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 
....
```

Either give that unnamed `div` a name (id), and then `$().show()` it with jQuery, or just hide the actual `#contact_thanks` `div`.

So instead of:

```
<div style="display: none">
      <div id="contact_thanks" style="......
```

Have it like:

```
<div id="give_the_div_a_name_either_way">
      <div id="contact_thanks" style="display: none"
```

And then with a bit of jQuery: `$("#contact_thanks").show();`

Should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, can you explain exactly where I need to put that jQuery so it doesn't affect my other colorboxes?

Comment: Well it should not affect any of your other colorboxes, as it only works with `#contact_thanks`. I would put it in the head of your doc.